# Looping a JSON feed using ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**ANSWERED**

Thanks to everyone that has replied on this post.  Thanks to Kevin (Best Solution for the loop) and thanks to Deepak for the sort functionality.

I am going to try find a pagination solution for this data on the site, but any further help would be appreciated.

Thanks again all!

**ORIGINAL QUIESTION**

I am hoping that you can help me out.  I have a JSON feed (which I have validated and is working perfectly on http://jsonlint.com/).  I have set up the page on my side and I can parse one result no problem.  Thing is there are many results in the feed and I need the jQuery to return all the results.  The example I am showing here has 11 results, but some of the other pages have up to 300 results. So this is a two part question.

My scripting knowledge is being able to change given code, but writing it myself is not possible (I am in the process of teaching myself though)

1. How do I return all the results?
2. How do I paginate the results, say 15 per page?

I am using the [Cross Domain Ajax](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) plugin by JAMES PADOLSEY to pull the data - is this the right terminology even?

The jQuery code I am using is:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://dealer.mustek.co.za/public-content-api.html?content=dealers&province=limpopo",
        success: function(response) {
            var headline = $(response.responseText).text()
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(headline); //parse JSON
            console.log(json_obj);
            var output = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.user_id; i++)
            output += "<div class='dealer'>";
            output += "<dl>";
            output += "<dt>Company Name</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].company_name + "</dd>"
            output += "<dt>Company Description</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].company_description + "</dd>";
            output += "<dt>Email Address</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].company_email + "</dd>";
            output += "<dt>Contact Number</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].contact_number + "</dd>";
            output += "<dt>Website URL</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].website_url + "</dd>";
            output += "<dt>City</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].city_suburb + "</dd>";
            output += "<dt>Physical Address</dt>"
            output += "<dd>" + json_obj[i].physical_address + "</dd>";
            output += "</dl>"
            output += "<p>"
            output += "</div>";
            $('#dealer_limpopo').html(output);
        },
    });
});
});
```

And I am pulling the div into a test html page http://thegearbox.co/thisisatest/.

As you can see there is no problem with feed, all is working perfectly, just need that pesky line to loop through all the data.  Currently the

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.user_id; i++)
```

is not doing the job.

Any help would be super appreciated!

PS. is there any way to sort the data alphabetically, or am I just being cheeky asking for so much? :)

**UPDATE**

A HUGE thank you to everyone that has commented so far.  I have used @Kevin's solution below to show all the data using

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++)
```

I am using @Deepak's solution to sort the data alphbetically:

```
                json_obj.sort(function compare(a,b) {
            if (a.company_name < b.company_name)
            return -1;
            if (a.company_name > b.company_name)
            return 1;
            return 0;
            });
```

Can anyone help with the pagination?

Comment: How does you json look like? I suppose `user_id` is an integer, since you are looping over it.

Comment: I suggest looking into templates (e.g. http://handlebarsjs.com/), they make this sort of code easier to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for loop` should iterate once for each item in the [] json_obj.  In Javascript an array contains an inherit property length.  The value of the length property indicates how many elements are contained within the array.  Adding this to `for loop` tells it to iterate once per element in the array.

Change the loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++){
   //code omitted
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Ok, so that is part one answered. The loop is working now.  Please can you explain why it needs to be json_obj.length?  I don't see a field length in the JSON.  Sorry if this is an incredibly ignorant question.

Comment: @thegearbox I updated the answer.  Hopefully your familiar with an array.  Length is just the amount of elements in an array.

Comment: @the gearbox json_obj is array of your object, so array has length property

Comment: if its an array, it automatically has the length field in javascript. Use $.each() to keep it simple.

Comment: @kevin thanks! That makes a whole lot of sense now. Is there a way to paginate this now? I want to say that this is the best answer, but I am going to keep the thread open until both parts are answered if you don't mind.  Thanks so much guys though, this has saved many hours of turmoil and pain.

Comment: @DeepakMishra I would advocate using the `for..each` over `.each()` until a thorough understanding of arrays/iteration is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery's for-each loop.

if your json response object is an array.

```
$.each( json_obj, function(index, value) {
    // process the value 
    // append value.company_name, value.company_email etc. to output.
});
```

And, to sort your data on company name.

```
json_obj.sort(function compare(a,b) {
     if (a.company_name < b.company_name)
         return -1;
     if (a.company_name > b.company_name)
        return 1;

        return 0;
});
```

Comment: @kevin solution below fixed the feed loop perfectly. I tried a $.each earlier, but it didn't do the trick

Comment: Thanks @deepak! The sort is working perfectly now.  I have used Kevin's solution for the showing all data and your sort is working a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case `json_obj` seems to be a list so,

json_obj.user_id is undefined.
try this if you have single list.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj[0].user_id; i++)
```

or else use

```
$.each(json_obj,function(data,index){
//your html code here
})
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: What if `json_obj` is an empty array? What if there are 20 records, but the `user_id` of the first is 1? This is a basic array iteration, the `user_id` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to sort your data :

```
json_obj.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.company_name > b.company_name) { return 1; }
    if (a.company_name < b.company_name) { return -1; }
    return 0;
});
```

Then you may replace the `for` loop with [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get the output :

```
var output = jQuery.map(json_obj, function (row) {
    // build your HTML here
    return '<div>' + row.company_name + '</div>';
});
```

Finally :

```
$('#dealer_limpopo').html(output.join('')); // don't forget to join :)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have inserted this line here:        for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++){
    json_obj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.company_name > b.company_name;});
    output += "<div class='dealer'>";  Is this right?

Comment: @thegearbox Insert sorting before the `for` loop statement. But you should consider the `jQuery.map()` solution which is a bit simpler. I have amended my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", timeout: 60000, cache: false, dataType: "jsonp", url: strURL + "&callback=?",
    success: function (response) {
        objAttributes = response.Attributes;

        var List = "";
        if (objAttributes != null) {
            var iLoop = 0;
            var xLoop = 0;

            for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < objAttributes.Product.length; iLoop++) {             
                if (List.length > 0) List = List + ":";
                List = List + objAttributes.Product[iLoop].ID;
                List = List + "_" + objAttributes.Product[iLoop].ITEM;               
            }
        }


    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

This code may help you.

Answer (score 0):

your "json_obj" is an array.

change

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.user_id; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++) {
```

Comment: thanks, @Kevin below gave the same solution and it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

"All in one" answer :

```
var headline = $(response.responseText).text()
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(headline); //parse JSON
json_obj.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.company_name > b.company_name) { return 1; }
    if (a.company_name < b.company_name) { return -1; }
    return 0;
});
return jQuery.map(json_obj, function (row) {
    return [
        '<div class="dealer">',
            '<dl>',
                '<dt>Company Name</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.company_name, '</dd>',
                '<dt>Company Description</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.company_description, '</dd>',
                '<dt>Email Address</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.company_email, '</dd>',
                '<dt>Contact Number</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.contact_number, '</dd>',
                '<dt>Website URL</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.website_url, '</dd>',
                '<dt>City</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.city_suburb, '</dd>',
                '<dt>Physical Address</dt>',
                '<dd>', row.physical_address, '</dd>',
            '</dl>',
        '</div>'
    ];
}).join('');
```